# Is the macro-nutrient difference between white and brown rice really that significant?

Tags: nutrition

I've often heard/read that brown rice is a better choice over white rice, because it contains the germ and the bran and so has higher levels of fibre, protein, fatty acids and so on... Unfortunately it takes quite a while longer to cook and doesn't really go well with some of the foods I like to eat with rice, so I usually stick to either basmati or parboiled rice... and feel guilty (I don't really, but it makes for a better story).

So I go into the shop and pick up three varieties of rice of the supermarket's own brand, i.e. all similar packaging/labelling, easily comparable nutritional information (all values per 100g as sold, i.e. dry, uncooked), take a photo of the nutritional information, and I find this:

Basmati rice:

> Fat 0.9g of which saturates 0.3g
>   Carbohydrate 76g of which sugars < 0.5g
>   Fibre 1.5g 
>   Protein 8.6g
>   Salt < 0.01g

Parboiled long grain rice:

> Fat 1g of which saturates 0.2g
>   Carbohydrate 77g of which sugars < 0.5g
>   Fibre 1.7g
>   Protein 7.2g
>   Salt < 0.01g

Long grain brown rice:

> Fat 2.8g of which saturates 0.7g
>   Carbohydrate 81g of which sugars 1.3g
>   Fibre 1.9g
>   Protein 6.7g
>   Salt < 0.01g

So this brown rice, which everybody knows as being high-fibre, contains just under 12% more fibre than parboiled rice? And a whopping 27% more fibre than basmati rice, which is about the whitest looking rice you can find? Is that it? It also seems to have the lowest protein content of all the rice varieties looked at here, how is that? I'm really confused by this. I can see a few explanations here:

1. The difference in fibre really is that significant, although I can't see it, especially since the absolute values aren't very high either.
2. The numbers are wrong. Well, I would like others to repeat this "experiment"/investigation in their area to see what they come up with.
3. Brown rice really isn't any better for you than white rice, with regards to fibre intake.
4. The are differences in the nutrient content of different varieties of rice that are more significant than just the mere brown/white distinction

Comment: The numbers don't even add to the same totals

Comment: @Paparazzi is that relevant? Different water content? How does affect the comparison of the fibre content?